# Валидация телефоного номера через бэк

Tags: php, laravel

```
'phone' => 'required|string',
```

Нужна валидация, и я так понимаю это делается через регулярку?
Вот так должна выглядеть маска +7-777-570-77-10
всегда +7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, вы можете использовать [регулярное выражение](https://regex101.com/r/8GZSOu/1): `^\+7-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$`:

- `^`: начало строки
- `\+7`: экранированная строка *+7*
- `\d{3}`: 3 цифры
- `$`: конец строки

Добавить его в валидацию можно с помощью правила [`regex`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-regex):

```php
'phone' => 'required|string|regex:/^\+7-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/i',
```

Comment: благодарю,  не как не могу научиться регулярки писать)

Comment: `^\+7(?:-\d{3}){2}(?:-\d{2}){2}$`